# How to return variable defined in Task in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

I have a class `Artist`, and below is a function to create a new `artist` and insert it to my library array. Because `insertToArtists(artist:)` is a asynchronous function, I have to wrap it in `Task`. But I also want my `newArtist` to return the `artist` just created.

My code is like below, but Xcode told me an error: `No 'init' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'Artist'`

```
func newArtist(name: String, notes: String, artwork: NSImage?) -> Artist {
    Task {
        let artist = Artist(name: name, notes: notes, artwork: artwork)
        await insertToArtists(artist: artist)
        return artist
    }
}
```

But if I make my code like this below. It won't work right. It seems that it returns `artist` before it's been `insertToArtist(artist:)`. How can I return `artist` after it's been inserted. I would appreciate your help.

```
func newArtist(name: String, notes: String, artwork: NSImage?) -> Artist {
    let artist = Artist(name: name, notes: notes, artwork: artwork)
    Task {
        await insertToArtists(artist: artist)
    }
    return artist
}
```

Comment: How and where is `func newArtist(` used?

Comment: How about `func newArtist(name: ...) async -> Artist` and put it into a `Task` on the caller side?

Comment: First possibility : you mark your newArtist as async and remove task. Second possibility : you add a closure that will be executed when insertToArtist is finished and that have the newArtist as parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys. It work properly. But I'm still worried. Because I'm going to call `func newArtist(name: ...) -> Artist` in another function `@MainActor func checkCreate()` which is used to update UI. If I use `newArtist(name) async -> Artist`, would it block main thread when some suspension occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it would be useful to know how `newArtist` is used, but I believe you will need to make it async as well.

```swift
func newArtist(name: String, notes: String, artwork: NSImage?) async -> Artist {
    let artist = Artist(name: name, notes: notes, artwork: artwork)
    await insertToArtists(artist: artist)
    return artist
}
```

And then use `Task` where you are calling `newArtist`

```swift
func whereYouUseNewArtist() {
   //YourCode
   Task {
      //YourCode
      x = await newArtist(name: name, notes: notes, artwork: artwork)
      //YourCode
   }
//YourCode
}
```

If you need to update your UI with the result of `newArtist`, remember to do it in the main thread. You can do it by adding `@MainActor` to where you use it. Example:

```swift
let artistToShowOnUI: Artist
@MainActor func whereYouUseNewArtist() {
    Task {
       artistToShowOnUI = await newArtist(name: name, notes: notes, artwork: artwork)
    }
}
```